# cite truncation biblatex-apa does not work

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm using the `biblatex-apa` package with Biber as the backend programme. With the package comes - as far as I understood - following: when mentioning a citation for the first time, all Authors should be named, in subsequent citations there should appear only the first authors name + et al.

The truncation does not work in my document, it shows all 4 authors all the time, no matter how often I use them.

Since I couldn't find any help on the internet, I decided to post it here. Does someone see a mistake?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{apa.bib}
@article{Zitat, author = "Name Nachname and Name1 Nachname1 and Name2 Nachname2 and Name3 Nachname3", 
title = "Titel des Artikels", 
journaltitle = "Zeitschrift", 
volume = "10", 
number = "4", 
pages = "518--532", 
date = "2015", }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=7, maxcitenames=7]{biblatex}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa} \providecommand{\apashortdash}{-}
\addbibresource{apa.bib}
\shorttitle{}
begin{document}
\parencite{Zitat}\\
\textcite{Zitat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a minimal example document with your question!

Answer (score 2):

You override the `apa` style by adding `style=authoryear`. Remove that (and the other options such as  `maxnames` which defaults to 7 for the `apa` style), and you should be fine.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Zitat, author = "Name Nachname and Name1 Nachname1 and Name2 Nachname2 and Name3 Nachname3", 
title = "Titel des Artikels", 
journaltitle = "Zeitschrift", 
volume = "10", 
number = "4", 
pages = "518--532", 
date = "2015", }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber, ]{biblatex}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa} \providecommand{\apashortdash}{-}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\shorttitle{}
\begin{document}
\parencite{Zitat}\\
\textcite{Zitat}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]