# How do I use “Trad et al. 2002 ” citation for more than two authors?

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

I am trying to use biblatex for citation. Whenever I am trying to use more than two authors for citation instead of using "et. al." , citation show the name of these three authors like this : D. O. Trad, Ulrych, and Sacchi, 2002 instead of Trad et al. (2002).

```
@article{trad2002accurate,
title={Accurate interpolation with high-resolution time-variant Radon transforms},
author={Trad, Daniel O and Ulrych, Tadeusz J and Sacchi, Mauricio D},
journal={Geophysics},
volume={67},
number={2},
pages={644--656},
year={2002},
publisher={Society of Exploration Geophysicists}
```

}

I am using it as :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{paper References.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{INTRODUCTION}

Reconstruction of seismic traces is important to provide a good sampling rate (\cite{cai2014data})

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I tried to change the style of the bibliography using ieee, Chicago, natural, apa, mla but I can't get Trad et al. 2002 as was I expected.

Comment: Your document loads `style=apa` (of `biblatex-apa`), which is a comprehensive implementation of the citation guidelines of the American Psychological Association (6th ed. of the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association). There are quite specific rules for the number of authors displayed in citations in APA style. The output you seem to want is not compatible with that. Since `biblatex-apa` was specifically written to implement APA style as far as possible, there are fewer customisation options. In your case I suggest to drop `style=apa` in favour of `style=authoryear`...

Comment: ... where `maxcitenames=2` should do what you want.

Comment: ...  or where `maxcitenames=1` and `mincitenames=1` should do what you want.

Comment: @PaulGaborit `mincitenames=1` is already the default value for all standard styles (since they set `minnames=1`), so it need not be set explicitly. I prefer `macitenames=2` over `maxcitanames=1` because the former will not shorten lists of two names such as "Sigfridsson and Ryde" to "Sigfridsson et al.".

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114442/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456888/35864, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454275/35864. Mildly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452032/35864, also interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505531/35864.